# How to prevent browser from fetching the same href repeatedly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a freshman in react ,I want to write a react component of  getting the member info of a team by teamId.

**React code**

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import UserTable from './pm_user_table';
import {Form,Modal,Input,Button} from 'antd';
const FormItem = Form.Item;

class PMBody extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      curTeam:this.props.curTeam,
      memberList:[]
    }
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    console.log('component mount');

  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.curTeam !== this.state.curTeam){
      this.setState({curTeam:nextProps.curTeam});
    }
  }
  

  render(){
    let {getFieldProps} = this.props.form;
    const teamId = this.state.curTeam;
    var myFetchOptions={method: 'GET'};
 fetch("http://localhost:3001/teamMembers/" +this.state.curTeam,myFetchOptions)
 .then(response=>response.json())
 .then(json => {
    this.setState({memberList:json});
   }
 ).catch(function(){
   console.log("error");
 });
    let memberList = this.state.memberList;
    const body = memberList !='' ?
      <UserTable dataSource={memberList}  actions={this.props.actions} />
    :
      ''
    ;

    return (
     
        <div>
          {body}
        </div>

     ) 
        
}

PMBody.PropTypes = {
  curTeam:PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default PMBody =Form.create({})(PMBody);
```

By  the network view in chrome devtool,It seems that the browser request the same url repeatedly.

[image]

[image]

So why it fetch the same url repeately?

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding the purpose of the [`render()` method](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#render).

React calls `render()` to update your component anytime anything changes.  It must be pure and should not interact with anything else.

You should move that to `componentDidMount()`.